# How can I trigger a POST call on new emails?

Tags: email, events, webhooks, contextio

I am attempting to integrate email into my web application. Essentially, using Mandrill to send out an email to users, then, if any user responds to this email, I would like that response to be pushed to my DB so that my web application users can see the response within the app and reply back if necessary. Basically, removing the need for an email client by having all the functionality within my web app.

Currently, using [Context.IO](http://context.io) to achieve this. However, I'm finding their service to be inconsistent at best, and unusable at worst.

Is there an alternative? Obviously, a key point here is authenticating my web application and granting it permission within my users' email accounts. ContextIO currently handles that fairly elegantly, it's just not reliable on firing off webhooks when emails are received.

Comment: I'm trying to work with Context.IO for the first time, I want to get data of inbound email every time I receive a new email in my C# code, did you figure it out?

Comment: Hey, we ended up bailing on Context.IO in favour of PostmarkApp, which is much more consistent, albeit a cost solution.